# Como extrair as informações de uma Array no MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, gostaria de saber como faço para puxar as informações da `array` do meu banco de dados, segue como está no meu banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo, gostaria de saber como extraio essa informação: *{'pt' => 'Promoção de Férias', 'en' => 'Vacation Promotion'}* na hora de passar pro PHP.

Código que estava utilizando para extrair do banco de dados:

```
$stm = $DB->readDB('news', 'WHERE Featured = "yes" ORDER BY ID, RAND() DESC LIMIT 1');
foreach ($stm as $key) {
    $title = eval($key['Title'][0]);
    $url = $Translate->set('href')['news'].'loja/'.$key['ID'].'-'.$Modulo->tirarAcentos($title, true);
```

Código que estava utilizando para salvar no banco de dados:

```
$stm = $DB->createDB('news', 'Title, SubTitle, Category, Message, Featured', '"{'.U_LANG.':'.$title.'}", "{'.U_LANG.':'.$subtitle.'}", $category, $message, "yes"');
return $stm;
```

Comment: Isso parece um formulário, não um banco de dados. Seria melhor mostrar o SELECT realizado, e a informação bruta.

Comment: Na hora que você preenche o formulário com seu idioma, o sistema automaticamente traduzir pra linguagens que você adiciona ao seu website, então quando envia pro banco de dados, ele envia como se fosse uma `dict`, ai agora preciso extrair essa `dict` do banco de dados pro site com PHP, é isso que eu desejo.

Comment: É e sobre o `=>` ajeitei, ele tá assim agora: `'pt':'Título'`.

Comment: Não, não desejo gambiarra, por isso vim pedi ajuda, porque no `python` eu tenho o script, mas não sei passar pelo php, agora me ajude então se você tem a forma certo, por favor.

Comment: Talvez `json_encode` e `json_decode` fossem melhores para o seu caso (mesmo assim, talvez ainda tenha jeito melhor). `json_encode` para transformar o array em um formato textual, com pares, e `json_decode` para recuperar. O PHP também tem `serialize` e `unserialize`

Comment: Não entendi uma coisa, no seu screenshot está com 2 dados entre { }, mas no seu código de salvar tem um par só de nome e valor. Se é pra recuperar somente um par, poderia simplesmente fazer algo como `$title= json_decode( $key['Title'] );` assim terá `$title['pt']` sendo "promoção de férias"

Comment: Veja um exemplo: https://ideone.com/fqM520

Comment: Já que invocaram a palavra `gambiarra` nem seria necessário mudar nada no banco, veja https://ideone.com/cw9wuT

Comment: com mais uma lingua https://ideone.com/163fCa

Comment: Leo, senão for pedi demais, você poderia colocar o conteúdo desses 3 links num gibit um num bloco de notas online e me enviar o link? Por que meu chrome não quer abrir esses links

Comment: @Akatsuki teste na sua maquina um script separado com essas linhas: `<?php` | `$campo = '{"PT":"o rato","EN":"the mouse"}';` | `$array = json_decode($campo, true); // true é array, false é objeto` | `print_r($array);` | `echo 'Português '.$array["PT"].PHP_EOL;` | `echo 'Inglês    '.$array["EN"].PHP_EOL;` - é o que tinha no meu IDEONE, é que lá você já ve o resultado - lembre de quebrar as linhas onde eu pus a barra vertical (|)

Comment: blz Leo, Bacco funcionou sim esse seu ficando assim: `Array ( [PT] => o rato [EN] => the mouse ) Português o rato Inglês the mouse `

Comment: O meu é a mesma coisa, o Leo fez um fork do código que eu já tinha enviado e acrescentou o replace da `=>`, só isso.

Comment: Galera OBRIGADO por TUDO MESMO, funcionou perfeitamente: `Português: Promoção de Férias`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Converta a string no formato JSON usando a função  [**str_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php), substituindo `=>` por `:` (sua string é uma mistura de matriz PHP e formato JSON).
- Então, você pode usar a função [**json_decode()**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) com o segundo parâmetro definido como `true`, para obter um array associativo

[veja funcionando aqui](https://rextester.com/UTB52259)

```
    $retornoBanco= '{"pt" => "Promoção de Férias","en" => "Vacation Promotion"}';
    $retornoBanco=str_replace('=>',':',$retornoBanco);

    $array = json_decode($retornoBanco, true);

    print_r($array);

    echo 'Português '.$array["pt"].PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Inglês    '.$array["en"].PHP_EOL;
```

> idealmente seria salvar no banco em um formato `JSON` válido, então você só precisaria usar o `json_decode`

```
 {"pt":"Promoção de Férias","en":"Vacation Promotion"}
```

> evitando assim o replace

Comment: É irei salvar logo assim, pra não ter o replace

Comment: @Akatsuki, ok, missão cumprida! vou remover a resposta

Comment: Deixa ai pow, vai saber alguém precisa futuramente.

Comment: OBRIGADO MANINHO, FUNCIONOU PERFEITAMENTE: `Português: Promoção de Férias`